# WPF application with Windows authentication

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-authentication

I have a simple wpf client (few text boxes) that uploads some data to a web service. And I want to use windows authentication to go with my application.

I am checking in OnStartup of App.xaml, whether or not the user is authenticated. My question is around what is the meaning of Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated.

I don't want my application to be used from outside my network as it is connecting to a web service and uploads data. But my assumption is as long as you run this application from inside any windows network the above mentioned property will always return true?

So how do I find out if the application is being run from inside my network. I don't think checking domain name or role name is any different, because I can always setup a domain and name it whatever I want. I don't want to prompt user for username or password of any sort.

How do you check Identity of user against a particular AD (AD might not be publically available). Basically the application should only works from my local network or through VPN.

Answer (score 1):

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAINNAME");
var result = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName);
```

If the result is null, then the user does not exists in the AD domain.

You can also user DirectorySearcher class to query AD based on a filter criteria. This is more useful only if you would like to retrieve additional details about the user like contact, email address etc.

Comment: Query will resolve against the AD controller of the network where the app is being run. That still won't tell me if it's being run from my network or some foreign network

Comment: Since you are using a web service you can restrict it to Network Service Identity type. You can also restrict access to the service to only specific network or ip address through the web.config using the <ipSecurity> tag.

Comment: I can put all the restriction at web service level. At simplest I can always authenticate against a username and password as my web service header, or as you said IP based restriction. But that's not the question, it is more around windows authentication and restricting access to WPF client and not the web service

Comment: At WPF client level the most you could do is query the AD and any restrictions have to be imposed through server level. Atleast, that's what I understand and I am happy to be corrected. If you need to restrict access to the WPF client so that it doesn't open outside your network, you can always query the AD and validate at startup. So unless you have been validated against AD due to any restriction imposed at Service level or AD level, you would not be able to run the application. Having said that, I myself will be curious to know if there are any options of handling it from client side.